# How to use enum value in SqlQuery?

Tags: ignite

Currently query like this does not work in Ignite if we use enum values on the right side:

`SqlQuery query = new SqlQuery(MyTable.class, "enum_field = 'ENUM_CONST'");`

but it works if setArgs is used.

`SqlQuery query = new SqlQuery(MyTable.class, "enum_field = ?");
query.setArgs(MyEnum.First);`

So my question is how to use plain sql string without setArgs to do the query with enum value inside?

Comment: Have you tried supplying enum ordinal as numeric const?

Answer (score 0):

it will be supported in a further version, you can track the following ticket: 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-4575
this ticket will bring enum support for plain string SQL queries.

Comment: The "fix version" in the ticket is not specified. What is the "future" version in which this fix will be included. Is it 2.7?